# Script to search specific string with within a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to this site and shell scripting.  I am still very much a novice and haven't had much success scripting because I am "attempting"  to learn on my own.  I was hoping one of you script guru's could get me on the right track.  Here's the situation:  I am a network engineer and often I need to find specific lines of code within 100's of files.  For instance I might need to find out which devices are running specific code. Typically what I will do is the following which does exactly what I need it to do.

fgrep -w "" * | sort -t/ -k5 -n

I normally have to go to the directory where my configuration files are located and then pop whatever I am looking for in between the quotations to get my search result.  What I would like to do is write a script that will ask me what I am searching for, then search the directory I am in, and then return the results.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Diz

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.bashrc` file, or whatever config file is loaded when you login:

```bash
mygrep() { fgrep -w "$1" * | sort -t/ -k5 -n; }
export -f mygrep
```

This sets up an alias that you can then use to search - use double quotes if you have a search string with spaces in:

```
$ mygrep SEARCH_PATTERN
$ mygrep "SEARCH WITH SPACES"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter string you want to search?" str

find . -type f -exec grep "${str}" {} \;
```